# Automated Execution of Selenium with Activated Extension

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-ide

I want to run several Selenium tests automatically in Google Chrome from a .side file.
Therefore, I need an activated extension. Also, I want to start the tests automatically and the first test should start again as soon as the last finishes.
Since I want to run the tests automatically (and not clicking through the Selenium IDE), I thought about using selenium-side-runner. However, I could not find an option to use the activated extension and selenium-side-runner starts a new Google Chrome window for each test. Instead, I would like to run all tests in sequence on the same window with the activated extension.

Does anybody know whether there is a way to use selenium-side-runner for my requirements? Or does anyone have other suggestions on how I can execute my tests automatically?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to run the test in sequence is to remove the check mark "Run in parallel" in the [Suite properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXiin.png) window.